# Adobe Flex/AIR on Mac: How to bundle programs with my app

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe

I have a bunch of bash scripts and binaries I need to take with my app, so that the ActionScript can call them. Some of them need to be in the user directory in order to run properly.

I was thinking of making a folder src/assets/tools, which will put them in the /Applications folder, and then from AS, upon installation copy them into user folder. Would this be ok, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was thinking of making a folder
>   src/assets/tools, which will put them
>   in the /Applications folder, and then
>   from AS, upon installation copy them
>   into user folder. Would this be ok, or
>   is there a better way?

If you create a custom installer; then this seems possible.  If you use the Adobe AIR default installer, there is no way to move files around during the install process.  You may be able to move them on first run of the application.  But, even if you do that, you won't be able to execute said scripts / binaries from within an AIR app.

I believe your best bet is to look into using the [NativeProcess APIs](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBYQFjAA&url=http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/interacting_with_native_process.html&rct=j&q=Flex%20NativeProcess&ei=bxHITa-SJsbi0QHV4rn_Cg&usg=AFQjCNH-HlN5bvZnkpRbIFqeDVCNeegVFg&cad=rja) to distribute the binary / scripts with your app.

Comment: I'm having trouble following the tutorial. If I run the attached DMG I get this "This application requires an update to Adobe AIR that is not available for your system."

Comment: If I try and compile with MXMLC and pack with ADT, MXMLC reports this "Error: only one source is allowed in the filespec". I think I need to go back a few steps and learn how to make native installers with ADT.

Comment: This now works. I placed sh file into assets, then on the first run I copied it from File.applicationDirectory to File.applicationStorageDirectory, and it worked fine. I had to export release build from FB, which produced SWF only not AIR, and then create a native installer with ADT. Very similar process to the link you provided only that that tutorial is pretty old and it won't work if you follow step by step.